# SetOptions error message upon launching Mathematica v.12

Tags: initialization

When launching Mathematica v.12, before opining any notebook,  I get the following message:
[image]

It does not afffect the execution of my notebooks, but it is annoying and I would like to understand how to get rid of it. I have read similar and previous questions/answers. I took a loook at the init.m file, but it is exceedingly involved. Is there a way to reset the Argument Label Style option and how? Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your init.m (`FindFile["init.m"]`).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I did open the init.m file, but , frankly, I did not know what to check. That is the reason of asking for advise.